# AJAX and php POST problems

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to pass to a PHP file cellnumber. My AJAX isn't even working, when I try 
alert("test"); in the ajax.onreadystatefunction() it won't print.

My javascript getrow(t) function gets called every time someone clicks on a cell in a table
and the result is the cell turning into green. I want to ultimately enter this data into a postgres table using php.

Thanks for all the help!
Vlad

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//gets the row and column number
function getRow(t) 
{
    var col=t.cellIndex;
    var row=t.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var testTable = document.getElementById("testTable");
    t.style.backgroundColor = "#33CC66";
    var cellnumber = (row*15 + col);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //use ajax to enter into visitedCells
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        // Call a function when the state changes.
       if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) 
       {
           ajax.open("POST", insertCoordinates.php, true);
           ajax.send(cellnumber);    
       }
       else
       {
           alert("Error:" + ajax.status + "and " + ajax.statusText);
       }
    }
}
</script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
         ajax.open("POST", insertCoordinates.php, true);
         ajax.send(cellnumber);
```

should be outside `ajax.onreadystatechange`

just befor `}//getRow`

you actually don't have the request executed

should be like that:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
//use ajax to enter into visitedCells
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
  if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
       alert('success');    
  } else {
       alert("Error:" + ajax.status + "and " + ajax.statusText);
 }
}//onreadyState

ajax.open("POST", insertCoordinates.php, true);
ajax.send(cellnumber);
```

probably won't work in IE

should use a construction like that:

```
try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

but the best way is to use jQuery ...easy and safe